# The right way to use php in jquery function

Tags: php, jquery

Do I use the php in jquery function the right way? Because for editing I use NuSphere PhpED and it says "unexpected ','" but if I run the page its working, I don't get any error.

```
<?php
$luna = $month;
$an = $year;
?>
<script>
$(function() {
    get_data(<?php echo "$luna"; ?>, <?php echo "$an"; ?>);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with your code above.

Comment: Look for PHP variable to javascript. Thousand of answers. Really this is a pretty common question, please search your own.

Comment: @Dipaks: You will love to read this: [JavaScript and HTML Script Tags](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quotes are just in the wrong place.

```
<?php
$luna = $month;
$an = $year;
?>
<script>
$(function() {
    get_data("<?php echo (int) $luna; ?>", "<?php echo (int) $an; ?>");
});
</script>
```

Comment: No, depending on what `$month` or year actually contains, this is not correct. Neither in the question nor in the answer. But anyway, that was not even asked for.

Comment: Either way, quotes aren't needed around the PHP variables in the echo command.

Comment: Placed the quotes and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @hakra it contains numbers from 1 to 12 and the year contains numbers as-well

Comment: Your basic issue is, that your IDE does not parse inline PHP code that is placed inside a script tag inside some HTML. Sure this is not trivial to solve, however nowadays some IDEs exist that get it managed.

Comment: No problem. I'm guessing you're using numbers 1-12 as strings and not integers? If not, the original code should have worked.

Comment: @Kieran The original code worked just fine, it was the IDE that was complaining.

Answer (score 3):

That should work fine - as far as the jQuery is concerned, it will never see the PHP tags or code, only the end values.

It looks PhpEd is choking on the PHP tags within Script tags and returning a false error.

Robin

Comment: +1 (if I would still have the votes) for actually reading the question :)